# Changing font style of KableExtra table from Helevitica to Arial

Tags: r, fonts, knitr, kable

I am trying to change the font style of a KableExtra table text. The standard is Helevitica and I would like to change it:

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
library(knitr)


library(kableExtra)
```

```
kable(mtcars,digits=2, type="html",align=NULL) %>% column_spec(1,width ="2in") %>%
      column_spec(2,width = "1in") %>%
      column_spec(3,width = "1in") %>%
      column_spec(4,width = "1in",italic=T) %>%  kable_styling(full_width = F) %>%
  kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover","condensed"))
```

Comment: look into the package 'extrafont'  and it will help you change fonts in your tables and output

Comment: Btw, please don't post code like `rm(list = ls())` in questions unless it's crucial to demonstrate the problem. No one wants to copy paste your question code and accidentally run that line. (And there should never be a need for it at the top of  `knitr` document anyway...)